# How to specify where to look for cypress.json file in Cypress container?

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm trying to run Cypress tests from docker image.
I'm using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM cypress/included:4.8.0

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY cypress.json /usr/src/app/cypress.json
```

In the docs I found I can run tests like this:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/services/cypress -w /usr/src/app --entrypoint=cypress cypress/included:4.8.0 run
```

This gives me error saying it can't find cypress.json in `/usr/src/app`

`services/cypress` is where the Dockerfile is located.
I copied the file over to `/usr/src/app` in Dockerfile so I don't understand why it complains it can't find it.

Can I get any feedback on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are using to run (docker run -it -v $PWD:/services/cypress -w /usr/src/app --entrypoint=cypress cypress/included:4.8.0 run) is running the  "**cypress/included:4.8.0**" image that doesn't have your *cypress.json* file.

First, you need to build your own image using the Dockerfile you've built. The dockerfile contains instructions to copy your cypress.json file within a layer in your image.

```
docker build -t TheNameOfYourImage .
```

Then, you can run this image:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/services/cypress -w /usr/src/app --entrypoint=cypress TheNameOfYourImage run
```